# Explain this behaviour with usage of eps for double comparison

Tags: matlab, double, precision

Here is the data:

```
probs_caseA_1 = reshape([0.06285693429791894300 ],[1  1]);
probs_caseA_2 = reshape([0.06285693429791905400 ],[1  1]);
probs_caseB_1 = reshape([0.93714306570208106000 ],[1  1]);
probs_caseB_2 = reshape([0.93714306570208095000 ],[1  1])
```

`caseA` and `caseB` are two mutually exclusive events, so their probabilities sum to 1:

```
>> probs_caseA_1 + probs_caseB_1 - 1 <= eps(1)

ans =

     1

>> probs_caseA_2 + probs_caseB_2 - 1 <= eps(1)

ans =

     1
```

The suffix `_1` and `_2` denote two different ways of generating the case A and B probabilities. Of course conceptually the two probabilities are the same for case A, and for case B.

Why do I get the following behaviour when I do this comparison:

```
abs(probs_caseA_1 - probs_caseA_2) <= ...
    max(eps(probs_caseA_1), eps(probs_caseA_2))

abs(probs_caseB_1 - probs_caseB_2) <= ...
    max(eps(probs_caseB_1), eps(probs_caseB_2))
```

which gives:

```
>> abs(probs_caseA_1 - probs_caseA_2) <= ...
    max(eps(probs_caseA_1), eps(probs_caseA_2))

ans =

     0

>> abs(probs_caseB_1 - probs_caseB_2) <= ...
    max(eps(probs_caseB_1), eps(probs_caseB_2))

ans =

     1
```

Note that this is saying that the case B probabilities are the same but those for case A are not, no matter whether method 1 or 2 was used to calculate it, yet we already show that the sum of the case A and case B probabilities are (machine) equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have more zeros after the decimal point with your variables "`caseA`". So `eps(caseA)` and `eps(caseB)` won't give you the same value ! `eps(x)` returns the positive distance from abs(x) to the next larger floating-point number of the same precision as x.

```
eps(caseA) < eps(caseB)
```

but

```
(probs_caseA_1 - probs_caseA_2) = (probs_caseB_1 - probs_caseB_2)
```

So your two `abs(...) <= max(...)` potentially give different results

you notice the difference if you try to write:

```
eps(0.01)
eps(0.001)
```

each time that you add a zero you will be closer to the next next larger floating-point number.

You can read [this article](http://matlabgeeks.com/tips-tutorials/floating-point-numbers-in-matlab-2/) for more details